# Problems with my dataset's shape trying to build a RNN with tensor flow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to build a RNN for classification with 625 possible classes. But I'm having problems

```
print(x_train.shape)
(5356, 1)

print(y_train.shape)
(5356, 625)
```

And my test dataset shape is basically the same as the train's shape dataset (It has been more or less normalized).

```
x_train

0   -34015.923376
1   -34161.563272
2   -34067.947314
3   -29068.385784
4   -34074.431654
...

print(y_train[0]) 

[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0.]
```

here is the code of my neural network, I'm having problems with *model.fit* because of the shape of the test dataset.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM

# x_train.shape[1:] => (1,)

model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(2496, input_shape=(5356, 1), activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(LSTM(2496, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))

model.add(Dense(1248, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(valores_distintos, activation='softmax'))

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6)

model.compile(
   loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
   optimizer=opt,
   metrics=['accuracy'],
)

model.fit(x_train,
          y_train,
          epochs=3,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

I'm aware that in the first layer, I'm supposed to have an input that follows this rule:

```
# Input(shape = (T,D)) for RNN
# T = T is length of time sequence
# D = D is the number of features
```

But I'm stuck trying to make It work because of my dataset's shape. Any ideas on how to make It work? I feel like I'm almost there.

Answer (score 0):

The input of the LSTM is always is a 3D array. (batch_size, time_steps, seq_len)
so try to expend your input.

try this:

```
x_train=np.expand_dims(x_train, axis=-1)
y_train=np.expand_dims(y_train, axis=-1)
```

Comment: Just did that, I got the following error:  `ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_4" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 5356, 1), found shape=(None, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)`

Comment: can you show me the shape of x_train and y_train befor and after you added the code.
because in first you showed that your data in in 2D.

Comment: Shapes: x_train-> (5356, 1) and y_train-> (5356, 625). Then It becomes (5356, 1, 1) and (5356, 625, 1).

Comment: If i set my input shape as "input_shape=(5356, 625)", I get "ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_9" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 5356, 625), found shape=(None, 1, 1)"

Comment: If I define my input shape as "input_shape=(1, 1)", I get a different error.

Comment: @viceconsul_tecktips Always specify error messages, people cannot guess them. But seems the issue is solved.